# Getting the absolute pathname in php

Tags: php

Consider the following scenario: I have a vhost defined to some paths on my home folder.

say `~/web/project-name/` is my root. such that when i point to `http://some-name/` it points to the `index.php` inside `~/web/project-name`.

I've a Model-View-Controller framework (self-made/minimal) and my views contains different client side links (`js`, or `css`, or `a href`) Since I made my working folder root, i used absoulte path names (for instance `/client/css/my.css` ).

Now a friends comes in takes my projects. Copies it to `/var/www/` So, now the contents of my website is not root, so my links in the views does not work?

What is the best way to mitigate the above problem?

I tried defining a constant `ROOT` as `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__))` in my index.php, but it returns the absolute path like `/home/cipher/...`

I want to make a function such that it returns the path of my index.php relative to the web root! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: erm... isn't `/client/css/my.css` a relative path rather...?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Ain't got much time right now, but please see http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php & http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php